# PHP Script Performance Invariable to Different Processors/Builds

Tags: php, mysql, performance, runtime, cpu

I've run the following PHP function on two different machines and consistently seen little difference in runtime - Ex. 40 sec vs 40.5 sec. Why is this?

**The Two Different Builds:**

- 2.3Ghz 8-Core Intel Core I9, 16GB RAM
- 3.8Ghz 12-Core Ryzen 9 3900x, 32GB RAM

I know that PHP runs scripts on a single core, but I'm unsure as to why the difference in clock speeds between the two processors accounted for no difference in runtime.

**The Function:**

This function takes a parent product, looks through its components for either a part or assembly - if a part - recursion, if not add to global variable. I know it's bad practice to use global variables, but in my application this makes sense for me.

```
<?php 
$masterPickList = [];

function listBuilder($itemNo, $multiplier){
    global $masterPickList;
    include "bin/inventoryConn.php";
    $assemblies = [];
    $AssemblySelect = "SELECT products.PRD_COMP_ITEM_NO,products.PRD_STR_QTY_PER_PAR, itemInfo.ITEM_DESC1,itemInfo.ITEM_DESC2,itemInfo.ITEM_P_AND_IC_CD,itemInfo.ITEM_USER_DEF_CD,itemInfo.ITEM_NO,itemInfo.ITEM_PUR_UOM 
    FROM products INNER JOIN itemInfo ON products.PRD_COMP_ITEM_NO = itemInfo.ITEM_NO WHERE products.PRD_STR_PAR_ITEM_NO = '{$itemNo}' ORDER BY PRD_COMP_ITEM_NO ASC;";
    $AssemblyResult = mysqli_query($conn, $AssemblySelect) or die("Bad Query: $AssemblySelect");
    
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($AssemblyResult))

    {
            if ($row['ITEM_P_AND_IC_CD'] !== '11' && $row['ITEM_P_AND_IC_CD'] !== '11A' && $row['ITEM_P_AND_IC_CD'] !== '90')
            {
                if (strpos($row['ITEM_NO'],'50-') !== false)
                {
                    $masterPickList[$itemNo]['SCD'][$row['ITEM_NO']]['ITEM_NO'] = $row['ITEM_NO'];
                    $masterPickList[$itemNo]['SCD'][$row['ITEM_NO']]['ITEM_DESC1'] = $row['ITEM_DESC1'];
                    $masterPickList[$itemNo]['SCD'][$row['ITEM_NO']]['ITEM_DESC2'] = $row['ITEM_DESC2']; 
                    $masterPickList[$itemNo]['SCD'][$row['ITEM_NO']]['QTY'] = intval($multiplier) * intval($row['PRD_STR_QTY_PER_PAR']);
                        if ($row['ITEM_USER_DEF_CD'] !== 'P')
                        {
                            $masterPickList[$itemNo]['SCD'][$row['ITEM_NO']]['PICK'] = '*Do Not Pick*'; 
                        } elseif ($row['ITEM_USER_DEF_CD'] == 'P')
                        {
                            $masterPickList[$itemNo]['SCD'][$row['ITEM_NO']]['PICK'] = '';
                        }
                    $masterPickList[$itemNo]['SCD'][$row['ITEM_NO']]['UM'] = $row['ITEM_PUR_UOM']; 
                }
                else
                {
                    $masterPickList[$itemNo]['COMP'][$row['ITEM_NO']]['ITEM_NO'] = $row['ITEM_NO'];
                    $masterPickList[$itemNo]['COMP'][$row['ITEM_NO']]['ITEM_DESC1'] = $row['ITEM_DESC1'];
                    $masterPickList[$itemNo]['COMP'][$row['ITEM_NO']]['ITEM_DESC2'] = $row['ITEM_DESC2']; 
                    $masterPickList[$itemNo]['COMP'][$row['ITEM_NO']]['QTY'] = intval($multiplier) * intval($row['PRD_STR_QTY_PER_PAR']);
                        if ($row['ITEM_USER_DEF_CD'] !== 'P')
                        {
                            $masterPickList[$itemNo]['COMP'][$row['ITEM_NO']]['PICK'] = '*Do Not Pick*'; 
                        } elseif ($row['ITEM_USER_DEF_CD'] == 'P')

                        {
                            $masterPickList[$itemNo]['COMP'][$row['ITEM_NO']]['PICK'] = '';

                        }

                    $masterPickList[$itemNo]['COMP'][$row['ITEM_NO']]['UM'] = $row['ITEM_PUR_UOM']; 
                }
            

            
            } 
            else if ($row['ITEM_P_AND_IC_CD'] == '11' || $row['ITEM_P_AND_IC_CD'] == '11A' || $row['ITEM_P_AND_IC_CD'] == '90')
            {   
                $masterPickList[$itemNo]['COMP'][$row['ITEM_NO']]['ITEM_NO'] = $row['ITEM_NO'];
                $masterPickList[$itemNo]['COMP'][$row['ITEM_NO']]['ITEM_DESC1'] = $row['ITEM_DESC1'];
                $masterPickList[$itemNo]['COMP'][$row['ITEM_NO']]['ITEM_DESC2'] = $row['ITEM_DESC2']; 
                $masterPickList[$itemNo]['COMP'][$row['ITEM_NO']]['QTY'] = intval($multiplier) * intval($row['PRD_STR_QTY_PER_PAR']);
                if ($row['ITEM_USER_DEF_CD'] !== 'P')
                {
                    $masterPickList[$itemNo]['COMP'][$row['ITEM_NO']]['PICK'] = '*Do Not Pick*'; 
                } elseif ($row['ITEM_USER_DEF_CD'] == 'P')

                {
                    $masterPickList[$itemNo]['COMP'][$row['ITEM_NO']]['PICK'] = '';

                }

                $masterPickList[$itemNo]['COMP'][$row['ITEM_NO']]['UM'] = $row['ITEM_PUR_UOM']; 

                $assemblies[] = $row['ITEM_NO'];
          
            }
    }   
    
    foreach($assemblies as $item) {
        listBuilder($item, $multiplier);
    }
}
```

Comment: Clock speed is just one of the nany features that determine overall speed of a cpu

Comment: and there is more than just "CPU speed" in how long a program takes to complete. You might be bottlenecking on IO at some place, or you're using enough memory to be pushed into swap. [and then IO bottleneck]

Comment: Also, pretty much any time you think "I can't do this without a global" is actually a case for a class/object. Though at a glance yours is just a recursive function and could probably be solved via a second pass at the logic and/or use of a reference.

Answer (score 2):

CPU speeds have not changed much since the year 2000.  Before that, it was a useful factor in performance.

MySQL spends some of its time transferring data between processes with itself and do/from the clients.  The performance of that, too, is not something to see much difference between two current servers or between an old server and a new one.

Almost everything is done serially, so multiple cores, drives, etc don't help when measuring a single task.

If everything is cached in RAM, the size of the RAM does not matter.

The only significant *hardware* improvement in the past decade is switching from HDD to SSD.  Everything is noise.